# Why does browser keep showing same version with webpack?

Tags: reactjs, gulp, webpack

I am using gulp& webpack to run my reactjs app. At the moment I have an issue that when I delete a file from my app it is still present in the browser chrome devtools. This is my webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: "./app/app.js",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        publicPath: "/dist/",
        filename: "myapp.js",
        sourceMapFilename: "myapp.map"
    },
    devtool: '#source-map',
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            loader: 'babel',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }]
    },
    devServer: {
        inline: true
    }

}
```

Even when I delete the dist folder completely the browser still shows the app? I have turned the cache off for chrome devtools. How can I show the latest version of my app with webpack?

Comment: maybe when you use webpack, it save your bundle.js in memory, not file, so you can still visit it. but if you restart webpack, you will find it, you lost it.

Comment: How to configure webpack so it picks up any changes straight away with restarting?

Comment: `module.export = {watch: true}`

Comment: It does not reload the app